# htaccess how to erase both php and html in url

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I have a problem with my website. I can't hide both .html and .php with url rewritting. I can hide one of them with my .htaccess file but not both at the same time.
I have tried to turn .php into .html but it doesn't work.
I've seen there is a lot of topics in stackoverflow for that subject. And I tried everything they said and broke my website a lot of time XD Nothing work.
I've tried solutions from other websites too but nothing work too.

Maybe I have missed something. Maybe I've done something wrong I don't know. Maybe my website is specific.
Here's my website : [elisabethpluquetportfolio.com](https://elisabethpluquetportfolio.com/)

Can you help me to solve this problem ? I'm lost.

Thanks :)

Edit :
Here's my actual htaccess :

```
#reecriture des liens pour éviter de laisser apparaître .html dans l'url
RewriteEngine On
#Remove .html suffix
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html  [L]

# 301 permanent redirect all .html to non .html pour rediriger les liens 
dont on a enlevé le html
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

If I do the same code for .php, by replacing .html by .php it doesn't work. It doesn't work because I can't have this code twice, for html and php.

I also have tried that :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

And it doesn't work.

I also tried to rename php in html but it doesn't work.
When it doesn't work, my browser tells me it can't find the page.

I don't have every codes I've tried because I've tried a lot without keeping a record. I should have done it, especially in order to not try the same thing several time and to show you what I've done.

Comment: Please paste the .htaccess code of what you have already tried into the question. Refer to [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Okay I do that, thank you. :)